# Is it possible to implement RLS in Power BI and create DAX filters based upon Active Directory Group Attributes?

Tags: powerbi, active-directory, dax, row-level-security

We are setting up row level security for a few of our datasets and are looking to setup filtering rules for our users. IS there a way to create a DAX expression that can work off of Windows AD group attributes within Power BI? Or would we need to design a method of importing attributes to their own table within the data model and query off of that instead?

Comment: You'll need to import AAD groups, their attributes (objects) and user mappings into a PBI table (and model it appropriately), then build RLS around that table.

Comment: Thanks @W.B. , it's a shame because I thought there'd be some overlap with integrations on it but just the same this should suffice. Just to add a followup, is there anything possible if we move to Azure Active Directory here?

Comment: @W.B. if you can make your comment into an answer then I can assign this as solved attributed to you.